# Vue js render with different request

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js, render

I am making an App with vue js and laravel using API,i am getting original data , but there is an optional parameter that i want to insert in the query to render the data accordingly, if there is no parameter detected , get the original query but if the parameter is there get the data that match the parameter.
i do not know how to do it with filter() and i tried to do it with axios , but it is not working

```
methods : {
        fetchTransactions() {
        axios.get(linkApi + "transactions/proprietaire/" + this.getProprietaireId,
        {headers : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + this.getToken}}
        ).then((res) => {
        this.transactions = res.data
        })
    },
  },
```

this one below is the function i created with the optional parameter

```
fetchTransactionsWithMois : function(event)
    {
        console.log(event)
        axios.get(linkApi + "transactions/proprietaire/" + this.getProprietaireId + "/" + $mois,
        {headers : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + this.getToken}}
        ).then((res) => {
            this.transactions = res.data
            console.log("trans",this.transactions)
        })
    },
```

this is the filter function that i talked about earlier, this one can do what i want to do but i do not know how to filter date by month with this

```
    filteredTransactions() {
        return this.transactions.filter( transaction => 
        transaction.proprietaire.nom.includes(this.proprietaireSelected))       
    },
}
```

i do not know how can i populate the data in vue js accordingly, i aldready did my research, didn't find the answer

Comment: is it more clear like that ?

Comment: Could you also show what you get from axios as a response data and also would be more understandable what you trying to achieve (f.e. show in code the data from your response and also show what you need to achieve)

Comment: What's the optional parameter? Please specify every comment you make. Your question is still unclear, make it short and straight to the point.